# Get post request from django python using Node JS

Tags: python, node.js, django

Using Node JS, I want to get the data that I posted.

in my views. py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = json.loads(request.POST.get("data"))
response = requests.post('http://localhost:3000/path/', data={
                                 'data': request.POST.get("data")})
```

in my node js

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const jsonParse = bodyParser.json()
router.post("/path", jsonParse, (req, res) => {
//I have some function here, but I needed to use the data from my 
django views.
console.log(req.body) //the console is {}, I want to get the data 
that I posted using the django views//})
```

Maybe my approach is wrong. I am new to node JS that's why I'm asking for help. I'm open to any suggestion. The django views are working. I just don't know how to receive that in Node JS way

Comment: may I know Post request of django working fine stand alone ?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the comment of Sir Harris brings me to check my django views. And I came up with solution. My node JS are now reading it

```
 data={'name':request.POST.get("device")}
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.post('http://localhost:3000/path', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```